# Multiple Where-clauses for Reserved Notation in Coq?

Tags: coq, notation, dependent-type

I've got a bunch of mutually-inductive datatypes declared using `with`, and I'd like to define a `Notation` for each of them that I can use while I'm defining them.

I'm aware of [Reserved Notations](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual014.html) and `with` clauses, but I can't figure out the syntax to define multiple notations which are avaliable to all of my mutually-inductive types.

Is it possible to define multiple Notations in `where` clauses, and if so, does anyone have an example of this I can see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example:

```
Reserved Notation "# n" (at level 80).
Reserved Notation "! n" (at level 80).

Inductive even : nat -> Set :=
  | ev0 : #0
  | evS : forall n, !n -> # S n
where "# n" := (even n)
with odd : nat -> Set :=
  odS : forall n, #n -> ! S n
where "! n" := (odd n).
```